# How to choose default Android project to launch in a multi-project package?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android package in Eclipse that consists of multiple projects. How do I choose which project launches first when I run it on an Android device?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You launch projects, not packages.

Comment: packages cannot contain projects? each project contains at least one package which is used to identify the app, do you mean you have multiple versions of a single project ?